# BULK INSERT large CSV file and attach an additional column

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, bulkinsert

I was able to use BULK INSERT on an SQL Server 2008 R2 database to import a CSV file (Tab delimited) with more than 2 million rows. This command is planned to run every week.

I added an additional column named "lastupdateddate" to the generated table to store the datestamp a row is updated via a INSERT trigger. But when I ran the BULK INSERT again, it failed due to mismatch in columns as there is no such a field in a raw CSV file.

Is there any possibility to configure BULK INSERT to ignore the "lastupdateddate" column when it runs?

Thanks.

-- EDIT:

I tried using a format file but still unable to solve the problem.

The table looks as below.

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
CREATE TABLE AAA_Test_Table 
   (
   Col1 smallint,
   Col2 nvarchar(50) ,
   Col3 nvarchar(50) , 
   LastUpdatedDate datetime 
   );
GO
```

The csv "data.txt" file is:

```
1,DataField2,DataField3
2,DataField2,DataField3
3,DataField2,DataField3
```

The format file is like:

```
10.0
3
1       SQLCHAR       0       7     ","     1     Col1               ""
2       SQLCHAR       0       100     ","     2     Col2               SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR       0       100     ","     3     Col3               SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

The SQL command I ran is:

```
DELETE AAA_Test_Table
BULK INSERT AAA_Test_Table
FROM 'C:\Windows\Temp\TestFormatFile\data.txt' 
WITH (formatfile='C:\Windows\Temp\TestFormatFile\formatfile.fmt');
GO
```

The error received is:

```
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 1 (Col1).
Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can using a `format file` as documented [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms179250%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and use that format with `bcp` command with `-f` option like `-f format_file_name.fmt`.

Well another option would be; import all the data (I mean all fields) and then drop the non wanted column `lastupdateddate` using SQL like

```
ALTER TABLE your_bulk_insert_table DROP COLUMN lastupdateddate
```

Comment: It can ignore the columns that are not specified/mapped in the format file?

Comment: Yes the one are not mapped will be ignored. Also, check edited answer for the alternative.

Comment: Sorry, the "lastupdateddate" column is what I added to the table and it does not exist in the raw CSV file. This column should as planned be automatically updated via a trigger.

Comment: Well if it's not in CSV then there is no issue at all .. right? if you don't want that column then just drop it.

Comment: Got it fixed myself. The problem was with the terminator with the 3rd field. Should have been ""\r\n"" instead of "","".

Comment: Great and yes that was the issue per your edited post. I just tried and it worked fine. you missed row/field terminator. See more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms191479.aspx